# WCF: Automatically disable MEX from DEBUG to RELEASE builds in VS2010?

Tags: wcf, mex, mex-bindings

I have code that automatically disbles fault information from flowing to clients when a RELEASE build of our product in installed.  I am wondering whether there is a clever way that we can also disable MEX metadata from being available in our RELEASE build.  Here is what I've done to automatically disable fault information, which I found at the following link: http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Faults/Fault-Contracts/.

```
    // Enables exceptions to flow to clients when built for debugging; 
    // Otherwise, no details go to client.
    public static class DebugHelper
    {
        public const bool IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults =
#if DEBUG
 true;
#else
      false;
#endif
    }

    // This service is singleton.  If other calls arrive while one is in progress, 
    // they are queued.
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
                     ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, 
                     IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = DebugHelper.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults)]
    public class OurService : IOurService
```

Answer (score 2):

If you configure your WCF service using a config file, then you could just have two separate configs - one for debug, one for release without the MEX endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the mex endpoint in code and thus compile it away

Comment: Ahhh...   I like both of your ideas, but this one is very appealing because I can use conditional compilation and don't have to maintain two config files.  This is the way to go!  Thank you Mark & Preet for your help! :) -- Mike